# Trying to take 1 random digit at a time

Tags: c++, string, random, int

I am new to cpp programing, and new to stackoverflow.

I have a simple situation and a problem that is taking more time than reasonable to solve, so I thought I'd ask it here.

I want to take one digit from a `rand()` at a time.  I have managed to strip of the digit, but I can't convert it to an `int` which I need because it's used as an array index.

Can anyone help?  I'd be appreciative.

Also if anyone has a good solution to get evenly-distributed-in-base-10 random numbers, I'd like that too... of course with a rand max that isn't all 9s we don't have that.

KTM

Comment: Are you willing to break out C++11?  It let's you generate arbitrary ranges using `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can use the modulus operator to get the digit of what number rand returns.

```
int digit = rand()%10;
```

As for your first question, if you have a character digit you can subtract the value of '0' to get the digit.

```
int digit = char_digit - '0';
```

Comment: This solution assumes that you are willing to accept some (small) bias: http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/16/how-much-bias-is-introduced-by-the-remainder-technique/

Answer (score 3):

If one wants a pedantic even distribution of 0 to 9 one could

1. Assume `rand()` itself is evenly distributed.  (Not always a good assumption.)
2. Call `rand()` again as needed.

   ```
   int ran10(void) {
     const static int r10max = RAND_MAX - (RAND_MAX % 10);
     int r;
     while ((r = rand()) >= r10max);
     return r%10;
   }
   ```

Example:
If `RAMD_MAX` was 32767, `r10max` would have the value of 32760.  Any rand value in the range 32760 to 32767 would get tossed and a new random value would be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

While not as fast as modulo-arithmetic implementations like `rand() % 10`, this will return evenly distributed integers and avoid perodicity in the least significant bits that occur in some pseudo-random number generators (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Other-random-number-generators.html).

```
int rand_integer(int exclusive_upperbound)
{
        return int((double)exclusive_upperbound*rand()/RAND_MAX);
}
```